# python - import namespace

Tags: python, import, namespaces, package

If I have a library like:

MyPackage:

- `__init__.py`
- SubPackage1

  - `__init__.py`
  - moduleA.py
  - moduleB.py
- SubPackage2

  - `__init__.py`
  - moduleC.py
  - moduleD.py

But I want that users can import moduleA like `import MyPackage.moduleA` directly. Can I implement this by write some rules in `MyPackage/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3):

In `MyPackage/__init__.py`, import the modules you want available from the subpackages:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import  # Python 3 import behaviour

from .SubPackage1 import moduleA
from .SubPackage2 import moduleD
```

This makes both `moduleA` and `moduleD` globals in `MyPackage`. You can then use:

```
from MyPackage import moduleA
```

and that'll bind to the same module, or do

```
import MyPackage

myPackage.moduleA
```

to directly access that module.

However, you *can't* use

```
from MyPackage.moduleA import somename
```

as that requires `moduleA` to live directly in MyPackage; a global in the `__init__` won't cut it there.